# Redirect specific routes if session is not set

Tags: php, symfony, routes

How can I redirect users to the main page if the session is not set? The session here is just the name they enter in their input field.

If I use conditions to check the session in the methods of the controller the code will just repeat. Is there a way to group the routes like in Laravel and apply configurations?

The code that repeats:

```
 if( $this->get('session')->get('fbSession'))
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home');
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried that just repeats?

Comment: @Jon question updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform this check to specified routes, you can implement event listener for kernel request event.

parameters.yml

```
routes_list:
    - app_messages
    - app_profile
    - app_something
```

services.xml

```
<service id="app.session_listener" class="AppBundle\EventListener\SessionListener">
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
    <argument type="service" id="router"/>
    <argument>%routes_list%</argument>
</service>
```

SessionLisener.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class SessionListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $routesList;

    /**
     * @param RouterInterface $router
     * @param array $routesList
     */
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, $routesList)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->routesList = $routesList;
    }

    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', -50)),
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (! in_array($request->get('_route'), $this->routesList)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($request->getSession()->has('fbSession')) {
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_home')));
        }
    }
}
```